# How to except/remove name on specified FormBuilder in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

I have a multi form, I want to just except this value when submit. I want just only to read only the circled data.

[image]

This is my current code.

```
addIngredient (itemId: string, name: string, quantity: number, unit: string): void {
    const ingControl = <FormArray>this.item.controls['ingredients'];

    ingControl.push(this.fb.group({
      itemId: [itemId || '', Validators.required],
      name: [name || '', Validators.required],
      quantity: [quantity || 0, Validators.required],
      unit: [unit || 'Grams', Validators.required] <-----------
    }));
  }
```

This is on the onSubmit[image]

Comment: can you please paste your submit method

Comment: I'm a bit confused of what you want to exclude. First picture you say that you only want to values from the circle, which is grams, then in other picture you say you want to remove the value with `grams`?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if your asking for this :

```
submit(formvalue: any){
  //you may creat an object
  let object: any = {
    'itemId': formValue.itemId,
    'name': formValue.name,
    'quantity': formValue.quantity,
    'unit': "",
  };
 // or whatever you lik
 formvalue.unit = "";

//YOUR API CALL
}
```

and in your html :

```
<form class="register-form" [formGroup]="yourForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(yourForm.value)"></form>
```